# Applying 3D sound effects in a 2D game using Monogame

Tags: xna, monogame

I'm having issues applying 3D sound using the monogame Framework.

I am currently using the latest version (3.6) and can't seem to get the sounds to play from different directions.  No matter what position I set the listener and the emitter, the sound that is played is always the same.  Here is the code I have, any help would be great.

```
SoundEffectInstance instance enemy.WarCry.CreateInstance();
AudioEmitter emitter = new AudioEmitter();
AudioListener listener = new AudioListener();
listener.Position = new Vector3(player.Position, 0);
emitter.Position = new Vector3(enemy.Position, 0);
instance.Apply3D(listener, emitter);
instance.Play();
```

Answer (score 0):

Monogame just supports mono-sound for 3D effects. Converting the stereo sound to mono, with free audio editors like Audacity, is the way to go.

Comment: This has nothing to do with the question. If they weren't already using mono sound effects the call to Apply3D() would have thrown an exception rather than always playing the sound the same as stated.

Comment: @RootVegetable I had the same problem and I didn't get any exception when calling Apply3D() with a stereo sound file. This bug cost me many days back then and this definitely solved it.
Maybe they added a exception in newer builds.

Answer (score 0):

For those still fighting this, there is a Scale to this.  I believe it's +/- 100 units.

So if you emitter is over 100 units away from your listener, you probably won't hear anything.

The trick is figuring out the right scale for your viewport size.